# Setting font to any object that responds to :#selector(setter:object.font)

Tags: ios, swift, selector, uifont

I'm trying to rewrite this Objective-C method which works perfectly fine

```
+ (void)setFontName:(NSString*)fontName onObject:(id)object {
    if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(setFont:)]) {
        UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:((UIFont *)[object font]).pointSize];
        [object setFont:font];
    }
}
```

in Swift:

```
public static func setFontRewriting(fontName: String, object: AnyObject) {
    if object.responds(to:#selector(setter: object.font)) {
        let currentFont: UIFont = object.font
        let fontToSet = UIFont(name: fontName, size: currentFont.pointSize)
        object.font = fontToSet //doesn't work, getting various syntax errors
    }
}
```

Even if an object responds to this selector, I can't set a font to it. Neither does `object.setFont` work. Any suggestions?

Comment: object is of type AnyObject. You have to cast it before calling the setter.

Comment: Please read this: [SWIFT AND THE CURIOUS CASE OF ANYOBJECT](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/09/24/swift-anyobject.html) Maybe help you understand a little more about swift and AnyObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

`object.setValue(fontToSet, forKey: "font")`